# How to generate truncated Javadoc?

Tags: parsing, javadoc

I encountered a problem with Javadoc generation. I would like to create a truncated Javadoc consisting only of specific comments, specifically - test cases (which are described by every @Test annotation), packages and classes, all other information is not needed. Is it possible to limit other elements in Javadoc while generating it without parsing it ?
For example:

```
 /**
   * <b>Test case A:</b>
   * 
   * <ol>
   *  <li>Navigate to main application</li>
   *  <li>In actions drop-down select value = 'Run'</li>
   *  <li>Assert that application is running</li>
   * </ol>
   *
   **/
  @Test
  public void testMainApp() throws IOException {
      navigateToMainApp();
      selectAndExecute();
      Assert.assertEquals("Applications is not running: ", true, status.equals(RUNNING));  
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use maven to generate javadocs(http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html). You will be able to exclude packages and source files for which you do not want to create docs.
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I don't want to exclude some of the packages, I want to exclude unnecessary info from the javadoc: methods, constructors and etc. I want to have a simple documentation containing only of test cases. I'm trying to do it with [Doclet API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/doclet/overview.html)